# Bashing [bash2zsh]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

[bash2zsh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash2zsh) has 10 questions, none of which have anything to do with the website [bash2zsh](http://bash2zsh.com) or its associated book, *From Bash to Z Shell*. Most of them aren't even really in the vein of "what is the Zsh equivalent of this Bash script?"

I can't say this tag has done any harm, but it probably doesn't do anyone any good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I concur, this is tag is useless, especially considering its lack of tag-wiki. I removed this tag from all the 10 questions it appears on. The roomba script should take care of it and remove it completely within a couple of days.

Comment: Seems like it was already done.