# rm -rf [.bash-script]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I ran into a question tagged [.bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.bash-script).

- 8 questions
- no info
- no tag wiki

What is this supposed to be? Why the dot? Shouldn't only high-rep users be able to create tags? If so: what is this supposed to be? If the dot should be removed: why [bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash-script) and not [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash)?

Bottom line: shouldn't this be burninated?

(Title courtesy of [@IKavanagh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552737/ikavanagh))

Comment: "Requests to have a tag "burninated" (or deleted) from the system. Use in case of uncertainty when requesting discussion, or when the popularity of the tag makes manual retagging followed by automatic culling of 0-question tags prohibitively difficult." retagging 8 questions and then deleting a 0-question tag doesn't seem too much work.

Comment: @Adriaan I am "uncertain" because someone created this tag for a reason, so I'm "requesting discussion".

Comment: Looking at the dates, it seems to be a fairly recent addition. Kill it now or have this same discussion again when there are hundreds of questions? Even only because of this awesome title - there should be a Meta badge for it -, I'd say go for it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was going to give a title along the same idea, but there was [a recent question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307158/bashing-bash2zsh) with the same concept:) IKavanagh's idea turned out to be much more original.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I agree with the burnination of this tag.  It doesn't make sense why [.bash-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.bash-script) should be used when [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) is acceptable.  I've gone through all of the questions and retagged and/or removed appropriately.

[image: Trogdor]

---

For posterity, here is the list of questions that had this useless tag as searching for questions in this tag now won't give any results.  You can check out the revision history to see that this useless tag was formerly part of it:

- [need help modifying a script to check service status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445039/need-help-modifying-a-script-to-check-service-status)
- [Replace newline with \n in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33418284/replace-newline-with-n-in-string)
- [FTP Script to move files from Suse server to ftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33409930/ftp-script-to-move-files-from-suse-server-to-ftp)
- [Creating a bootable .img file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404141/creating-a-bootable-img-file)
- [What does wait $! mean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375924/what-does-wait-mean)
- [Get values of columns of a file with tabs and newlines separating them read via bash script to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33187617/get-values-of-columns-of-a-file-with-tabs-and-newlines-separating-them-read-via)
- [Detecting key release in a Bash script in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186722/detecting-key-release-in-a-bash-script-in-linux)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33181189/how-i-can-detect-the-begin-and-end-of-session-in-a-so

Comment: The oldest question (2 weeks-and-bit) was from someone with only 20 rep. Can you find out how the tag got created to begin with, or is that a futile exercise?

Comment: @Jongware I have absolutely no idea how the heck the tag got created with a 20 rep user.  That was confusing to me as well.  It would be interesting to know how it actually got created.  However, I'm going to edit this post with a list of questions that had the old tag for posterity.

Comment: @Jongware Is it possible that a high-rep user accidentally created it, then later removed the bogus tag from their question, while leaving the tag in the system?

Comment: @AndrasDeak: That must be what happened. Only at 3 UTC are orphaned tags actually pruned, unless a mod gets involved.

Comment: @Deduplicator thanks. Talk about bad luck...

Comment: It's actually gone! (Well, for the not-25k rep user that is)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Tags without questions get removed frequently (I believe daily), so the high-user theory only makes sense if that happened "right before" the oldest question was asked.

Comment: @FooBar that's what I meant by "bad luck":) It doesn't make much sense anyway.