# Disambiguating "in-place", "mutate", the [in-place], [mutate] tags and the R verb dplyr::mutate

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

Several questions about disambiguation, tag and term definition, in a language-agnostic way:

1. Are the terms "in-place" and "mutate" strongly related, or totally synonymous?

   - "in-place" is preferred 8:1 by Python pandas, but "mutate" by R and other languages
   - Definition: Note "in-place" does **not** mean "without allocating any extra memory, or auxiliary variables. It only means "avoids copying the input". So Python `list.append/extend, obj.property = 'foo'` etc. are all in-place operations. This is often misunderstood. (see [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm),[2](https://www.interviewcake.com/concept/java/in-place))
   - "mutate" is used as a generic term, and often in Python: [3.1K Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+mutate)
   - "mutate" is also used in R, but 
     [most of the 21.6K mentions are specifically to dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BR%5D+mutate)
   - [2.4K Java mentions of "mutate"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+mutate), [1.4K C++ mentions of "mutate"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D++mutate), [4.3K JS mentions of "mutate"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D++mutate), and many other languages
   - the difference in whether call-by-reference/call-by-value is the default often creates confusion for users migrating from one language paradigm to another.
2. [in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in-place) tag

   - current definition: *"Use this tag on questions about algorithms that modify the data in-place, as opposed to making a copy. For example, in-place [sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sorting), in-place [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge), etc."*
3. [mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutate) tag

   - currently defined very narrowly as the R verb `dplyr::mutate`. This is not acceptable even if it was just within R, since (for example) the R `data.table` `:=` operator also does mutate. The R `dplyr` package does not "own" the word 'mutate'.
   - should it be redefined in a language-agnostic way? (see [3](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html))
   - is it synonymous to "in-place" (If no, give a specific explaining why not?)
   - please suggest a specific definition wording
4. Should [mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutate) and [in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in-place) be tag synonyms? or else should their definitions reference each other with "also called [mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutate)/[in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in-place)"? Or else what?

References:

Comment: Why any of this even exist? I have used both R and Python and never ever I had or read a question about "mutating objects", I had questions about "doing stuff with *X library*" or "understanding *X* behavior". I would find myself hard pressed trying to find a question where "mutate" or "mutation" or "in-place" is even on my search terms, much less someone in their actual expertise of programming. Yes, we describe some operation as "mutating objects" or "replacing in place", but that's not enough to merit their own tags.

Comment: @Braiam occasionally a question is really about mutation, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51903777/numpy-array-assignment-with-operator) (dupe and basic, but still). That being said, I'm not sure that the good questions in the subject are numerous enough to merit the existance of the tag.

Comment: @AndrasDeak ... still, don't know how a tag would have helped that user to get the answer to their question. The user didn't even know it was called mutating, so as tag it wouldn't be useful for it to make their question more discoverable to the people that are able to answer, yet it managed to get the answer it needed just by describing the expected behavior and the actual behavior. Even if you can think of many ways a tag could be applied to a question, if nobody uses it (or worse, agrees what does it mean), the value of the tag isn't over 0.

Comment: @Braiam: yes you would have learned the concept very early on (*"`list.sort()` sorts in-place, whereas the function `sorted()` doesn't"* or *"strings are immutable, in Python"*) , just not necessarily using the word 'mutate', like I said Python people tend to avoid the word, but they use the concept.

Answer (score 2):

"Mutate" and "in-place" aren't synonyms. I believe that mutation is a more generic concept, but it also isn't a superset of in-place things (i.e. there are in-place things that aren't mutation).

Mutation is a very general concept which describes a change in the internal state of an object. Any change. While any mutation is technically "in-place" because there's no other place to begin with, I believe describing certain mutating actions as "in-place" is just weird or confusing. I don't think appending to a list in python should be described as "in-place". I don't think setting an attribute on an instance should be described as "in-place".

The picture I have about "in-place" in the context of mutation is that it only really makes sense for operations that mutate a container in a way that some or all of its items change. This is the pandas meaning you take for granted: all the `inplace=True` keyword arguments in various pandas methods will mutate items in a container from input rather than copying. I thus believe your perception is biased by your familiarity with pandas, which makes you confuse "in-place" with generic "mutation".

On the other hand, "in-place" is not always mutating. How would you call the `+=` operator present in many languages? I believe it's fair to call it in-place addition (one of multiple possible names). However, even in python (which the both of us are familiar with) `x += 1` and `y += (1,)` (acting on an int and on a tuple, respectively) will not mutate, as these types are immutable (the names will be rebound to new objects that are constructed).

Whether or not we want to reclaim [mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutate) from R and make it a general tag is another question. It should be weighed whether using the tag for a single function makes sense (given 300+ existing questions with such use of the tag). I can imagine that it's worth making it more general. Are there experts in R's `mutate`? Are there experts in "mutation" in general? Either way, I don't think [in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in-place) is a synonym of [mutate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mutate).

While we're at it: let's kill [in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/in-place). The more I think about it the more it looks like a meta-tag.

Comment: *"there are in-place things that aren't mutation"* - give us an example?

Comment: @smci fourth paragraph

Comment: I had never heard '+=' called 'in-place addition operator'. But apparently it is. See also [How are Python in-place operator functions different than the standard operator functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772987/how-are-python-in-place-operator-functions-different-than-the-standard-operator)

Comment: *"While we're at it: let's kill [tag:in-place]"* No, this will multiply confusion, esp. since 'in-place' is widely used in packages and languages, and noone ever stops to discuss how it relates to mutate, and whether they differ. What's wrong with the suggestion I gave: have each definition reference the other?

Comment: @smci that works for me too. But I'm not sure tagging something with [in-place] actually adds anything to the post. Discoverability, focus for domain experts...I don't think so.

Comment: I still think the distinction you draw between 'mutate' and 'in-place' only on immutable primitives doesn't matter, because in both NumPy, pandas and R our typical data structures of interest (dataframe, series, vector, list, array/matrix, dict/hash, set) are mutable. (Let's not mention string). The distinction does matter to compiler writers. Essentially everywhere else, 'in-place' => 'mutate'. I wasn't really thinking of objects and properties, though.

Comment: You'll be sorry to hear that SO is so much more than the tools _you_ are familiar with, @smci.

Comment: that comment is seriously rude, considering I've spent hours researching this, citing sources, and collating SO. What does it tell you if all SO users couldn't come up with a proper definition of 'mutable' vs 'in-place' all these years? But you're not insulting them for not making an effort.

Comment: @smci if you look at burnination requests you'll see that SO users can't even be trusted to [type sane tag names](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309222/rm-rf-bash-script). Whether or not a set of tags exist with a given meaning is more chance than conscious design. You asked for my opinion (first in chat, then posting on meta) which I gave you. Your response is trying to convince me that I'm wrong and moving goalposts based on your views stemming from the technology you're familiar with. I'm sorry if you're offended but calling a spade a spade is not rude.

Comment: "It should be weighed whether using the tag for a single function makes sense" and that said function varies between libraries!